# If $a=a'$ mod $n$ and $b=b'$ mod $n$ does $ab=a'b'$ mod $n$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

So far this is my working out: 

$n|a-a'$ and $n|b-b'$ 
So $n|(a-a')(b-b')$

Expanding: $n|ab-a'b-ab'+a'b'$

I'm not sure what to do next. I need to show that $n|ab-a'b'$

Answer (score 6):

We can write $a' = a + n k$ for some $k$, and likewise $b' = b + n m$; then

$$a'b' = (a + nk)(b + nm) = ab + n(\text{stuff}) \equiv ab \pmod{n}$$

upon distribution the multiplication.

Comment: Since $a \equiv a' \pmod{n}$,we can multiply both sides by b to get $ab \equiv a'b \pmod{n}$. By $ab \equiv a(mod  n)b(mod  n) \pmod{n}$,we can conclude that $ab \equiv a'b' \pmod{n}$[since $b\equiv b' \pmod{n}$ ]. Is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 3):

In fact, $n^2$ divides your product, not helpful, as it turns out. Your strategy should have been to look at $ab-a'b'$ and show that it’s divisible by $n$. The trick is one you’ve probably seen already in calculus, to add and subtract a clever something. In this case, you write $ab-a'b'=ab-a'b+a'b-a'b'$, then factor the first pair and the second pair separately. *Voilà*.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:  since $n \mid (a - a')$, we have $a - a' = k_1 n$ for some integer $k_1$; thus $a = a' + k_1n$; likewise $b = b' + k_2 n$ for some $k_2$.  Now when we take $ab$ we get:

$ab = a'b' + a'k_2n + k_1na + k_1k_2n^2$,

so we see that $n \mid (ab - a'b')$. ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  A jovial Yule season to one and all,

and of course,

***Fiat Lux!!!***